# Como se puede validar un rango de fechas en Laravel Blade?

Tags: php, laravel-blade

Tengo 2 campos de fecha en una tabla llamada precios en mi base de datos, la hora de inicio y termino de una reserva (respectivamente).

En mi controlador mediante la siguiente variable, obtengo dichos campos:

```
use DB;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;

public function MyFunction(Request $request){

  $desde = "08:00:00";
  $hasta = "23:00:00";

  $now = new \DateTime();

  $price = DB::table('precios')
    ->join('complejo', 'complejo.id', '=', 'precios.complejo_id')
    ->get();

  return view('confirmar',['price'=>$price, 'now'=>$now]);
}
```

Luego en la vista muestro un campo el cual es el monto del precio de una reserva, de la siguiente manera:

```
    <tr>
        <td style="color: grey;">{{$prices->monto}}</td>
    </tr>
```

Y **mi problema** entra ahora, resulta que no sé muy bien como validar que los campos **hora_inicio** y **hora_fin** estén dentro de un rango de fechas el cual es validado junto con la **hora actual.**

Es decir, si la hora de inicio comienza a las **`19:00:00 Hrs`** y la de término finaliza a las **`23:00:00 Hrs`**, y actualmente son las **16:35:00 Hrs**, el precio a  mostrar deberia ser el siguiente:

```
'TABLA precios'

id|monto|hora_inicio|hora_fin
 1|20000|19:00:00   |23:00:00
 2|23000|15:00:00   |19:00:00
 3|18000|08:00:00   |13:00:00
```

Dicho en el ejemplo anterior el precio a mostrar deberia ser **23000,** porque el rango de horas va desde las `15:00:00` hasta las `19:00:00 Hrs`, y actualmente son las **16:35:00 Hrs**.

Pero en cambio no sucede eso, el precio que me muestra es siempre el de la primera hora. El de 15000, en la validacion, sin tomar la hora de verdad, que es como intento que funcione, esto en mi controlador:

```
$from = "08:00:00";


$now = Carbon::now();
$now->toTimeString();


$price = DB::table('precios')
    ->join('complejo', 'complejo.id', '=', 'precios.complejo_id')
    ->get();

//¿ES POSIBLE HACER ALGO SIMILAR COMO EN SQL?

/*EN SQL...
WHERE precio.hora_inicio AND precio.hora_fin 
BETWEEN curTime() AND '17:00:00'*/

/*AHORA EN EL CONTROLADOR. 
IF($price.hora_inicio && $price.hora_fin BETWEEN $now && '17:00:00')*/

/*ESTE ULTIMO (BETWEEN) REEMPLAZARLO POR UN OPERADOR QUE 
REALICE LA MISMA FUNCION QUE BETWEEN EN SQL, 
DE MOMENTO SE ME OCURRIÓ <= o >=*/

foreach ($price as $price) {
    if ($price->hora_inicio && $price->hora_fin <= $now && '23:00:00') {

        $valor = 23000;
    }else if ($price->hora_inicio && $price->hora_fin <= $now && '17:00:00') {

        $valor = 19000;
    }else if ($price->hora_inicio && $price->hora_fin <= $now && '13:00:00') {

        $valor = 15000;
    }else{
        $valor = 'No Aplica';
    }
}
```

Como ejemplo adicional, realice la siguiente consulta en la base de datos, obteniendo el resultado esperado. Si cambiaba la hora del sistema con la que se compara en la consulta, funciona siempre.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: que formato tiene `$now`? Otra cosa dentro del foreach tu hora_inicio solo coincide a las `08:00:00`

Comment: El formato que tiene `$now` es el siguiente, `DateTime @1548792806 {#434 ▼
  date: 2019-01-29 17:13:26.935330 America/Santiago (-03:00)
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En laravel 5.x podes hacerlo así:

```
$now = Carbon::now()->toTimeString();

$price = DB::table('precios')
->join('complejo', 'complejo.id', '=', 'precios.complejo_id')
->where('hora_inicio', '<', $now)
->where('hora_fin', '>', $now)
->first();
```

Laravel automáticamente interpreta el `carbon` y lo castea a `string`.
Podes usar el `first` ya que siempre vas a tener un solo valor, en caso que este fuera del rango, te va a devolver `null`. Para acceder $price->monto;

Comment: Al poner `->first();` me arroja un error `Trying to get property of non-object` agregue un `@foreach` para solucionar aquello (normalmente funciona) pero me arrojo otro error: `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`. Por lo que lo cambie por un `->get();` y ahora no muestra nada. ¿Alguna sugerencia amigo?

Comment: Si queres enviame la funcion completa y yo la miro con mas detalle.

Comment: A travez de este enlace te puedo enviar la funcion: [Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89025/validar-un-rango-de-fechas-en-laravel-blade)

Comment: Solo que me funciono, cambiando el ->first(), por un ->get(). Gracias

Answer (score 0):

- Utilizando `date`

  ```
   $now = date('H:i:s');  //obtienes 15:31:30
  ```
- si lo dejabas con `Carbon`

  ```
  $now = Carbon::now();
  $now->toTimeString()  //obtienes 15:31:30
  ```

Otros usos para `Carbon` https://styde.net/componente-carbon-fechas-laravel-5/